# Can we add a campaign field to the batch activities screen

Tags: activities

Can we add a campaign field to the batch activities screen?
My goal is to record attendance on CRM, through batching activities. I want to be able to put what the Campaign is for the specific event they attended when I batch activities

Comment: unlikely to be related but i just saw this thread also about Campaigns and entities https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/77fgsi6m4jbn8jdcjwqdu4gigr

Answer (score 2):

Braincreatives welcome to CiviCRM SE, By `batch activities screen` do you mean   'Update mulitple activities' option using from search actions? If so I believe you can add campaign field to a profile, use the profile to update activities in batches